# Convert the string 2.90K to 2900 or 5.2M to 5200000 in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Need some help on processing data inside a pandas dataframe.
Any help is most welcome.

I have OHCLV data in CSV format. I have loaded the file in to pandas dataframe.

How do I convert the volume column from  2.90K to 2900 or 5.2M to 5200000.
The column can contain both K in form of thousands and M in millions.

```
import pandas as pd

file_path = '/home/fatjoe/UCHM.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, parse_dates=[0], index_col=0)
df.columns = [
"closing_price", 
"opening_price", 
"high_price", 
"low_price",
"volume",
"change"]

df['opening_price'] = df['closing_price']
df['opening_price'] = df['opening_price'].shift(-1)
df = df.replace('-', 0)
df = df[:-1]
print(df.head())

Console:
 Date
 2016-09-23          0
 2016-09-22      9.60K
 2016-09-21     54.20K
 2016-09-20    115.30K
 2016-09-19     18.90K
 2016-09-16    176.10K
 2016-09-15     31.60K
 2016-09-14     10.00K
 2016-09-13      3.20K
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

assuming you have the following DF:

```
In [30]: df
Out[30]:
         Date      Val
0  2016-09-23      100
1  2016-09-22    9.60M
2  2016-09-21   54.20K
3  2016-09-20  115.30K
4  2016-09-19   18.90K
5  2016-09-16  176.10K
6  2016-09-15   31.60K
7  2016-09-14   10.00K
8  2016-09-13    3.20M
```

you can do it this way:

```
In [31]: df.Val = (df.Val.replace(r'[KM]+$', '', regex=True).astype(float) * \
   ....:           df.Val.str.extract(r'[\d\.]+([KM]+)', expand=False)
   ....:             .fillna(1)
   ....:             .replace(['K','M'], [10**3, 10**6]).astype(int))

In [32]: df
Out[32]:
         Date        Val
0  2016-09-23      100.0
1  2016-09-22  9600000.0
2  2016-09-21    54200.0
3  2016-09-20   115300.0
4  2016-09-19    18900.0
5  2016-09-16   176100.0
6  2016-09-15    31600.0
7  2016-09-14    10000.0
8  2016-09-13  3200000.0
```

Explanation:

```
In [36]: df.Val.replace(r'[KM]+$', '', regex=True).astype(float)
Out[36]:
0    100.0
1      9.6
2     54.2
3    115.3
4     18.9
5    176.1
6     31.6
7     10.0
8      3.2
Name: Val, dtype: float64

In [37]: df.Val.str.extract(r'[\d\.]+([KM]+)', expand=False)
Out[37]:
0    NaN
1      M
2      K
3      K
4      K
5      K
6      K
7      K
8      M
Name: Val, dtype: object

In [38]: df.Val.str.extract(r'[\d\.]+([KM]+)', expand=False).fillna(1)
Out[38]:
0    1
1    M
2    K
3    K
4    K
5    K
6    K
7    K
8    M
Name: Val, dtype: object

In [39]: df.Val.str.extract(r'[\d\.]+([KM]+)', expand=False).fillna(1).replace(['K','M'], [10**3, 10**6]).astype(int)
Out[39]:
0          1
1    1000000
2       1000
3       1000
4       1000
5       1000
6       1000
7       1000
8    1000000
Name: Val, dtype: int32
```

Comment: @JosephMNjuguna, you are welcome! I've added a step-by-step explanation to my answer - please check...

Comment: @MaxU..........Now I know how to use regular expressions with pandas.........Been at it for days

Comment: And for billions: `df.Val = (df.Val.replace(r'[KMB]+$', '', regex=True).astype(float) * df.Val.str.extract(r'[\d\.]+([KMB]+)', expand=False).fillna(1).replace(['K','M', 'B'], [10**3, 10**6, 10**9]).astype(int))`

Answer (score 44):

```
def value_to_float(x):
    if type(x) == float or type(x) == int:
        return x
    if 'K' in x:
        if len(x) > 1:
            return float(x.replace('K', '')) * 1000
        return 1000.0
    if 'M' in x:
        if len(x) > 1:
            return float(x.replace('M', '')) * 1000000
        return 1000000.0
    if 'B' in x:
        return float(x.replace('B', '')) * 1000000000
    return 0.0

df['col'] = df['col'].apply(value_to_float)
```

Answer (score 26):

#### `DataFrame.replace` with `pd.eval`

I like MaxU's answer. You can considerably shorten this using `pd.eval`:

```
df['Val'].replace({'K': '*1e3', 'M': '*1e6'}, regex=True).map(pd.eval).astype(int)

0        100
1    9600000
2      54200
3     115300
4      18900
5     176100
6      31600
7      10000
8    3200000
Name: Val, dtype: int64
```

Slight modification will make this case insensitive as well:

```
repl_dict = {'[kK]': '*1e3', '[mM]': '*1e6', '[bB]': '*1e9', }
df['Val'].replace(repl_dict, regex=True).map(pd.eval)

0        100.0
1    9600000.0
2      54200.0
3     115300.0
4      18900.0
5     176100.0
6      31600.0
7      10000.0
8    3200000.0
Name: Val, dtype: float64
```

**Explanation**

Assuming "Val" is a column of strings, the `replace` operation yields,

```
df['Val'].replace({'K': '*1e3', 'M': '*1e6'}, regex=True)

0           100
1      9.60*1e6
2     54.20*1e3
3    115.30*1e3
4     18.90*1e3
5    176.10*1e3
6     31.60*1e3
7     10.00*1e3
8      3.20*1e6
Name: Val, dtype: object
```

This is an arithmetic expression which `pd.eval` can evaluate!

```
_ .map(pd.eval)

0        100.0
1    9600000.0
2      54200.0
3     115300.0
4      18900.0
5     176100.0
6      31600.0
7      10000.0
8    3200000.0
Name: Val, dtype: float64
```

Comment: if I want to add one more functionality to replace `-` with `0` would this be the right way to do `replace({'[kK]': '*1e3', '[mM]': '*1e6', '[bB]': '*1e9', '-':'0')}, regex=True)` ?

Comment: It does, just wanted to confirm.

Comment: For a DataFrame objects (multiple columns) use .apply(pd.eval) or .applymap(pd.eval). The .map method only works on a Series as in this example. ```df['Val'].replace(repl_dict, regex=True).apply(pd.eval)```

Comment: @DavidDarby `df['Val'].replace(repl_dict, regex=True)` will return a Series, did you mean `df.replace(repl_dict, regex=True)`? If you did, then you are correct in that `apply` allows you to generalize to multiple columns.

Comment: Yes, I should have used an example with a DataFrame as you did.

Comment: I prefer this method though I would suggest using something like `df.str.split("*", expand=True).astype("float").pipe(lambda x: x[0] * x[1])` in place of `df.map(pd.eval)`. 

In my case it was faster (207ms for map vs 60ms for split/pipe), plus you don't have the inherent dangers of using eval.

Comment: @Sean nice, how large was the test data? Also a correction that pd.eval is an arithmetic eval as opposed to python's built-in eval and so is safe.

Answer (score 3):

To further generalize cs95's answer I would do this:

```
df['Val'].replace({'K': '*1e3', 'M': '*1e6', '-':'-1'}, regex=True).map(pd.eval).astype(int)
```

since on some numeric values pd.eval has to multiply '-' by some other number which will result an error. (could not convert string to float '-')

Answer (score 1):

**You can use `numerize` library, too easy!**

```
pip install numerize
```

**Use**

```
print(numerize.numerize(1000))
print(numerize.numerize(100000))
print(numerize.numerize(1234567))
print(numerize.numerize(123456789))
```

**Result**:

```
1K
100K
1.23M
123.46M
```

Comment: The numarize library works only one way. 1.000.000 → 1M. Not the other way around, as OP has requested

Answer (score 1):

```
def value_to_float(x):
    try:
        x = x.upper()
        if 'CEN' in x:
            return float(x.replace('CEN', '')) * 10**303
        elif 'GO' in x:
            return float(x.replace('GO', '')) * 10**100
        elif 'QIT' in x:
            return float(x.replace('QIT', '')) * 10**84
        elif 'QAT' in x:
            return float(x.replace('QAT', '')) * 10**45
        elif 'TE' in x:
            return float(x.replace('TE', '')) * 10**42
        elif 'DU' in x:
            return float(x.replace('DU', '')) * 10**39
        elif 'UN' in x:
            return float(x.replace('UN', '')) * 10**36
        elif 'DE' in x:
            return float(x.replace('DE', '')) * 10**33
        elif 'NO' in x:
            return float(x.replace('NO', '')) * 10**30
        elif 'OC' in x:
            return float(x.replace('OC', '')) * 10**27
        elif 'SP' in x:
            return float(x.replace('SP', '')) * 10**24
        elif 'SX' in x:
            return float(x.replace('SX', '')) * 10**21
        elif 'QI' in x:
            return float(x.replace('QI', '')) * 10**18
        elif 'QA' in x:
            return float(x.replace('QA', '')) * 10**15
        elif 'T' in x:
            return float(x.replace('T', '')) * 10**12
        elif 'B' in x:
            return float(x.replace('B', '')) * 10**9
        elif 'M' in x:
            return float(x.replace('M', '')) * 10**6
        elif 'K' in x:
            return float(x.replace('K', '')) * 10**3
        else:
            return float(x)
        return 0.0
    except Exception:
        return 0.0


def float_to_value(x: float):
    try:
        if x > 10**303-1:
            return str(x/10**303) + 'CEN'
        elif x > 10**100-1:
            return str(x/10**100) + 'GO'
        elif x > 10**84-1:
            return str(x/10**84) + 'QIT'
        elif x > 10**45-1:
            return str(x/10**45) + 'QAT'
        elif x > 10**42-1:
            return str(x/10**42) + 'TE'
        elif x > 10**39-1:
            return str(x/10**39) + 'DU'
        elif x > 10**36-1:
            return str(x/10**36) + 'UN'
        elif x > 10**33-1:
            return str(x/10**33) + 'DE'
        elif x > 10**30-1:
            return str(x/10**30) + 'NO'
        elif x > 10**27-1:
            return str(x/10**27) + 'OC'
        elif x > 10**24-1:
            return str(x/10**24) + 'SP'
        elif x > 10**21-1:
            return str(x/10**21) + 'SX'
        elif x > 10**18-1:
            return str(x/10**18) + 'QI'
        elif x > 10**15-1:
            return str(x/10**15) + 'QA'
        elif x > 10**12-1:
            return str(x/10**12) + 'T'
        elif x > 10**9-1:
            return str(x/10**9) + 'B'
        elif x > 10**6-1:
            return str(x/10**6) + 'M'
        elif x > 10**3-1:
            return str(x/10**3) + 'K'
        else:
            return str(x)
    except Exception as err:
        return '0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df["Val"] = df["Val"].replace(['€','K','M'] ,'' , regex=True).astype(float) * df["Val"].replace(['€','K','M'] ,['',1000,1000000] , regex=True).astype(int)
```

This code is used to convert the string in the format "€##.#K" or "€##.#M" into int

Comment: You should at least describe what the code does in simpel terms.

Comment: df["Val"].replace(['€','K','M'] ,'' , regex=True).astype(float) * df["Val"].replace(['€','K','M'] ,['',1000,1000000] , regex=True).astype(int) "Small correction to take care of the decimal point

Comment: This code is converting string in the format "€##.##K" or "€##.##M" into int.

Comment: Just edit your answer and add the information, don't write the additional info as comments.