# Convert 600M to 600,000,000 and 7K to 7000 in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to update values in a couple of columns,

```
dt = pd.DataFrame([["value1","600M"],["value2","70K"]])
dt.columns = ['val', 'som']
```

I want to update 600M to 600000000 and 70K to 70000.
For this, I wrote a function,

```
def convert_unites(val_to_convert,conversion = 'numeric'):
        if(conversion == 'numeric'):
    units_numeric = dict([
        ('K', 1000),
        ('M', 1000000),
        ('B', 1000000000)
    ])
    if(val_to_convert.str.contains('K')):
        return int(val_to_convert.str.replace('K',''))* units_numeric['K']
    elif(val_to_convert.str.contains('M')):
        return int(val_to_convert.str.replace('M',''))* units_numeric['M']
    else:
        return 0
```

Calling the function

```
dt.apply(lambda x: (convert_unites(x)) if x.name in ['som'] else x, axis=0)
```

I got this Error

```
ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index som')
```

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39684548/convert-the-string-2-90k-to-2900-or-5-2m-to-5200000-in-pandas-dataframe) might help

Comment: One column is fine, what if I have values in two different columns.