# Invalid syntax Pandas Python If statement Lambda function

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I'm having a syntax error when applying the lambda function, however, I'm using the same lambda structure as in other functions. Is it an issue with the apply function on pandas?

```
for column in list2:
        print(column[-1])
        data[f'{column}'] = data[f'{column}'].apply(lambda x: str(x).replace('.','').replace('M','0000000') if (x[-1] == 'M'))
        data[f'{column}'] = data[f'{column}'].apply(lambda x: str(x).replace('.','').replace('B','0000000000') if (x[-1] == 'B'))
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use a conditional expression (A if B else C) and you omitted the `else` after the `if`.

Comment: @khelwood I added an else pass statement as well, but got the same syntax error

Comment: It has to be a value expression

Comment: It seems like you're tying to do something like [Convert the string 2.90K to 2900 or 5.2M to 5200000 in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39684548/15497888) I'd recommend adapting one of these approaches over a loop and apply with lambda.

Comment: `pass` is not an expression: it does not express any value.

Comment: You **cannot** use a statement inside of a lambda expression, only expressions. If you want to, just use a regular function definition statement

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

```
for column in list2:
    print(column[-1])
    data[f'{column}'] = data[f'{column}'].apply(lambda x: (str(x).replace('.','').replace('M','0000000')) if str(x[-1]) == 'M' else x )
    data[f'{column}'] = data[f'{column}'].apply(lambda x: (str(x).replace('.','').replace('B','0000000000')) if str(x[-1]) == 'B' else x)
```