# Applying a function to a dataframe does not work

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Now I have a data frame with entries like '7M'as a string where M is Million and I want to change it to 7000000 This is a look from the data frame

[image: Inpute Example]

I have tried to make a function to separate the numbers from the letter and changing the letter to a number and it worked

```py
def num_repair(x):
    if 'B' in x:
        l = 10**9
        x = x[:-1]
        x = pd.to_numeric(x)
        x = x * l
    elif 'TR' in x:
        l = 10**12
        x =x[:-2]
        x = pd.to_numeric(x)
        x = x * l
    elif 'M' in x:
        l = 10**6
        x = x[:-1]
        x = pd.to_numeric(x)
        x = x * l
    return(x)
```

and when I tried to apply it to the data frame it didn't give me anything
any help please?

Comment: Something like: [Convert the string 2.90K to 2900 or 5.2M to 5200000 in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39684548/15497888)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### TL;DR:

What you are looking for is `.applymap()`

#### Details:

Your method is actually written well and can be used in `.apply()` as-is, for a `pandas.Series` object, but I assume that if you are experiencing issues, it is due to the fact that you are probably using it for a `pandas.DataFrame`, against multiple columns.
In such a case, the argument passed to `num_repair` is actually of type `pandas.Series`, which `num_repair` is not really meant to support.
I can only assume, since the code that uses `num_repair` isn't given. Consider adding it for the completeness of the question.

If so, you can use it as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['1M', '1B', '1TR'],
    ['22M', '22B', '22TR'],
], columns=[1990, 1991, 1992])
df.applymap(num_repair)
```

output:

```
        1990      1991          1992
0       1000000   1000000000    1000000000000
1       22000000  22000000000   22000000000000
```

#### Side Note

If you want to apply it to all columns except the country, since the name may contain `B` / `TR` / `M` - you can do the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['countryM', '1M', '1B', '1TR'],
    ['countryB', '22M', '22B', '22TR'],
], columns=['country', 1990, 1991, 1992])
df.loc[:, df.columns.drop('country')] = df.loc[:, df.columns.drop('country')].applymap(num_repair)
df
```

output:

```
    country     1990        1991        1992
0   countryM    1000000     1000000000  1000000000000
1   countryB    22000000    22000000000 22000000000000
```

Comment: It worked ! thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Works fine on my toy example:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['32M', '13B', '33TR']})
>>> df['a'].apply(num_repair)

0          32000000
1       13000000000
2    33000000000000
```

Comment: I don't think it will if you work with more than one column