# How to sum price of human readable currency format?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, format, currency

I retrieve data from a website, the price column is 809.989K, 1.792M and I want to combine the numbers from the price column into a new column.

My dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
  "price": ["809.989K", "1.792M"]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

Desired output

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert values to floats numbers with `sum`, last add prefix by `si_format` library:

```
#pip install si_format
from si_prefix import si_format

#https://stackoverflow.com/a/39684629/2901002
out =  ((df.price.replace(r'[KM]+$', '', regex=True).astype(float) * 
              df.price.str.extract(r'[\d\.]+([KM]+)', expand=False)
                .fillna(1)
                .replace(['K','M'], [10**3, 10**6]).astype(int)).sum())

df['sum'] = si_format(out, precision=1).upper()
print (df)
      price    sum
0  809.989K  2.6 M
1    1.792M  2.6 M
```